# How do you write this loop as a list comprehension?

Tags: python

I have this code

```
lista = list()
for dict_genres in df['genres']:
    suport = list()
    for genres in dict_genres:
        suport.append(genres['id'])
    lista.append(suport)
```

How do you write it as a list comprehension?

Comment: note that you can use [] instead of list()

Comment: This will be a nested list comprehension. First try to rewrite the inner loop as a list-comp, then insert that as a value in a list-comp for the outer loop. `lista = [[genres['id'] for genres in dict_genres] for dict_genres in df['genres']]` should do.

Comment: Only because I see `df`, is this in pandas or numpy? If so, I'm sure there is a much more efficient solution than a comprehension/loop. And if it is please post an example of the `df`.

Answer (score 2):

With 1 level list-comprehension

```
lista = []
for dict_genres in df['genres']:
    lista.append([genres['id'] for genres in dict_genres])
```

With 2 level list-comprehension

```
lista = [
    [genres['id'] for genres in dict_genres]
    for dict_genres in df['genres']
]
```

Answer (score 1):

simply as:

```py
lista = [[genres['id'] for genres in dict_genres] for dict_genres in df['genres']]
```

Comment: Plenty of people have already added this exact answer.

Comment: but while i was writing it i didn't seen there solutions neither i know that they are also writting.

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop is

```
suport = [genres['id'] for genres in dict_genres]
```

So the entire thing would be

```
lista = [<snippet above> for dict_genres in df['genres']
```

Building lists of lists using list-comprehension can become a bit unreadable.